# I need a Minecraft Beta 1.7.3 server jar that has a correct md5, is there anywhere where I can get one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Question is in title above, correct md5 to compare to is cc263aa969f2d8621c5443a5a18897e2, but I can't find any files with that md5.
EDIT: I did try looking for it, but didn't know that it was a bug nor I could find it as a bug.

Comment: We don't do recommendations here at Arqade, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, it was not possible to download these early servers due to a bug: [MCL-5530](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-5530)

This bug is now fixed, so it should work again. If you read this because you have the same problem, then check your launcher version. If it's newer than the ones given as "fix version" in the report, your problem is something else.